# Bad Company 2 engineer antitank mine cap

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

So the mines you plant as engineer stays even if you die. But is there a cap of how much mines you can have at once in a map? I've planted mines in a few places before, and some time later I go back and the mines disappeared.

Actually, I assumed it disappeared, because right where it should be there were no holes or burn marks from the explosion that would result if ran over by vehicles or shot by someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can only have 6 Mines or C4s planted at any one time.  When you plant your 7th, the 1st one you planted is removed.

Also, I believe if you die they also disappear.

Comment: In my memories, C4 disappear when you respawn (don't disappear when revived by medic). But I suppose a mine should not have that respawn limit, it wouldn't be of any real interest, if it could disappear so easily...

Comment: Unfortunately it does have that respawn limit.  It's why your engineer using mines should try to stay out of the line of fire until his mines have gotten someone.

Comment: mines don't disappear after death, c4 disappear on both respawn and revive.

Answer (score 2):

As Weegee said, the first mine you planted disappears when you plant the seventh (and so on). However, as far as I know the mines do not have any other limit, thus they may stay the whole round unless you plant more mines or they detonate. I haven't confirmed this myself ingame though, I just read this on the EA BC2 forums.

Answer (score 1):

The anti-tank mines stay in place even if you change class; they only despawn when exploded or when 7th mine is placed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of 6 mines or c4 as weegee said but mines don't disappear but c4 does when you die.  Mines will remain as long as the round lasts or you stay on the server which ever comes first.